# convergence of a sequence of Dirichlet domains

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}^2$ be the hyperbolic plane , and $(\Gamma_n)_n$ a sequence of Fuchsian groups converging to a group $\Gamma$ (i.e. there exist isomorphisms $\tau_n:\Gamma\rightarrow\Gamma_n$ such that for all $\sigma\in\Gamma,\tau_n(\sigma)$ converge to $\sigma$.  )

Let  $Dir_n$ and $Dir$ be the Dirichlet domain  for $\Gamma_n$ and $\Gamma$ respectively. We know that the Dirichlet domain is a polygone with vertices.

My question:  how  to prove that the vertices of  $Dir_n$ converges to the vertices of  $Dir$?

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet domains are not unique; the same Fuchsian group has many different Dirichlet domains.

Because of that nonuniqueness, the straight answer to your question is there are counterexamples: let $\Gamma_n$ to be the constant sequence converging to itself otherwise known as $\Gamma$; take each $Dir_n$ to be one fundamental domain; and I can take $Dir$ to be a different fundamental domain.